# Find a kind of Chinese font avaliable in XeLaTeX

Tags: languages, cjk

I'd like to use a Chinese font similar to the text in the following figure.
I used the follow class and package in the preamble. What should I use in place of `SimSun` or modify something else? Thanks!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this code. use \newCJKfontfamily

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor,BoldFont=texgyreheros-bold.otf,ItalicFont=texgyreheros-italic.otf,BoldItalicFont=texgyreheros-bolditalic.otf]{texgyreheros-regular.otf}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

\newCJKfontfamily\poetryfont{STXINGKA.TTF}


 \setCJKmainfont[Color=textcolor,BoldFont={Hiragino Sans GB W6.ttf},ItalicFont={STKAITI.ttf}]{Hiragino Sans GB W3.otf}
 \newcommand{\mypoetry}[1]{\poetryfont\zihao{2} #1}
 \begin{document}
  归去来兮辞


  {\mypoetry{归去来兮！田园将芜胡不归？既自以心为形役，奚惆怅而独悲！悟已往之不谏，
    知来者之可追。实迷途其未远，觉今是而昨非。}}

  归去来兮辞

  In the Battle of the Falaise Pocket (12–21 August 1944) in the Second World War, Allied forces encircled and destroyed most of the German Army Group B west of the Seine river in a pocket at Falaise in northwestern France. It was the decisive engagement of the Battle of Normandy. The Americans had broken out from the Normandy beachhead, the Third U.S. Army under General George Patton was rapidly advancing, and British and Canadian forces were launching offensives south of Caumont and Caen. Adolf Hitler ordered Field Marshal Günther von Kluge, the commander of Army Group B, to conduct a counter-offensive at Mortain instead of withdrawing. Four depleted panzer divisions were not enough to stop the First U.S. Army, which converged with the British Second Army and the First Canadian Army on the Falaise–Chambois area, directed by the Allied ground forces commander, General Bernard Montgomery. German counter-attacks forced some gaps in the Allied lines, but by the evening of 21 August the pocket had been sealed, with around 50,000 Germans trapped inside. Many escaped, but losses in men and

  \end{document}
```

and you can get this
[image]

Comment: http://font.chinaz.com/150611506470.htm

Comment: I appreciate that native language communication is likely efficient here, but please bear in mind that others may also need to access the information: a translation of key points in English would be appreciated.

Comment: Let's switch to English @All_l thanks, I guess so. Could you please recommend an alternative or similar font, for example, xingshu (行书) or xingkai (行楷).

Comment: you can see my anwser.

Comment: @All_l When I use exactly your code with XeLaTeX, it gives the following errors.  Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \newCJKfontfamily
                     \poetryfont{STXINGKA.TTF}
?

Comment: the error is  i'm using the ctexart package, if you use the package article or report, please not use the \zihao{}.

Comment: @All_l when I use either package article or report and delete `\zihao{2}` in `{\poetryfont\zihao{2} #1}`, compile with XeLaTeX. It gives me the following errors:
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for loaded.
(d:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(d:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\size10.clo))
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \setmainfont 
                             
l.2 \setmainfont
                [Mapping=tex-text,
?

Comment: @All_l I really want to use the font given in your answer!

Comment: my environment is TeXLIVE 2017，i didn't meet the error.And i suggest you use the TeXLIVE 2017 and TeXstudio